# How to redirect example.com/folder/ to www.example.com/folder/?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to know how to redirect **example.com/folder/** to **www.example.com/folder/** using htaccess. At moment htaccess redirects **example.com/folder/** to **www.example.com**. This is what htaccess says at moment:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/] 

RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^folder$ /folder/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*) /$1 [L]
```

What changes are needed?

Comment: I managed to solve it. Sorry about the trouble. The solution was to simply add this to htaccess in addition to what was already there:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ 
RewriteRule ^folder$ /folder/ [L,R] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ 
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*) /$1 [L]

Comment: Consider to "answer" your own question. This way it' s clear that the question is solved. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Just use this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

First check that the *host* value is not empty (may be with HTTP/1.0).
The check if we already "use" *www* and then chrck for SSL (https)

If you want to keep subdomains intact, you should change the second line to this (*heads up* this is not 100% generic since you have to hardcode in your domain!):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
```